# How to do compound conditions in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, contains

I have following classes:

```
public class PriceSelectionsResponse
{
public Prompts Prompts { get; set; }
}

public class Prompts
    {
        public List<Prompt> prompt { get; set; }
    }

public class Prompt
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public object level { get; set; }
        public object message { get; set; }
        public object details { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to use an if condition where I want to check that if any `prompt` `level` is equal to "WARN" AND that prompt object also CONTAINS string "HOPPER" in `message`. How can I do that?

I tried this way, but cant figure out. How can I achieve this?

```
 if(PriceSelectionsResponseRootObject.Response.PriceSelectionsResponse.Prompts.prompt.Any(p => p.level == "WARN") && PriceSelectionsResponseRootObject.Response.PriceSelectionsResponse.Prompts.prompt.Where(p=>p.message.contains("Hopper")) {

    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a class called `Prompts` that just contains a `List<Prompt>`?  Why not have the collection directly on `PriceSelectionsResponse`?

Comment: What was the error? Seems like it should work

Comment: @DarrenYoung Actually we are mapping a json request into our model classes so can't help

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm object doesnot contain a definition for 'contains'

Comment: Oh well yeah your message needs to be string `message.ToString()` idk why you have it set to an object in your model. Should be string, but ToString() should work.

Comment: You're basically taking away the good thing about strongly typed language. You have defined data types, here you just have everything to an object. If you had them set to strings, then you wouldn't be in this mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your last statement is doing is saying if any of the prompts has `level == "WARN"` and any of the prompts has a message containing HOPPER (not necessarily the same prompt with level = WARNING) then go into the if block. What you want to do is check that *the same* prompt matches both conditions:

```
if(PriceSelectionsResponseRootObject.Response.PriceSelectionsResponse
    .Prompts.prompt.Any(p => p.level.ToString() == "WARN" && p.message.ToString().Contains("HOPPER"))
{
}
```

Comment: Any idea why am I getting 'Cast the left handside to type string' at `p.level.ToString() == "WARN"`

Comment: @zariakhan updated my answer, `level` is of type `object` so you need to do a `ToString()` before comparing it to a string, in your original post you missed that